# mysql stored procedure trying to hand over input parameter using vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5

I have a small vb.net application, trying to hand over input parameter to a stored procedure on a mysql server.

The problem is, the procedure can be excecuted but it only inserts the idorganisation leaving the projectno column empty.

this is my stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`user1`@`%` PROCEDURE `InsertProject`()
BEGIN

DECLARE prno varchar (45); 

INSERT Into project ( idorganisation, projectno) values (( select idorganisation from user where usercol1 = (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(USER(),'@',1))),
@prno);
END
```

my vb.net code:

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim con As New MySqlConnection(My.Settings.welddocconnectionstring)
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("InsertProject", con)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

    Dim prno As New MySqlParameter("@prno", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 45)
    prno.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
    prno.Value = "Test"
    cmd.Parameters.Add(prno)


    Try
        con.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        con.Dispose()
    End Try

End Sub
```

Thank you and best regards
Josch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to define `prno` as a parameter to your stored procedure, not declared as a [local variable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/stored-program-variables.html) within it; I adopt a convention of prefixing my parameter names with an underscore in order to avoid any ambiguity in subsequent expressions:

   ```sql
   CREATE PROCEDURE InsertProject(IN _prno VARCHAR(45)) ...
   ```
2. Your procedure only contains a single statement, so you don't need to enclose its body in a [`BEGIN ... END`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/begin-end.html) compound statement block.
3. `prno` is *not* a [user-defined variable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/user-variables.html), so don't prefix it with `@`.
4. You don't need to use a subquery to evaluate `SUBSTRING_INDEX()`:

   ```sql
   WHERE usercol1 = SUBSTRING_INDEX(USER(),'@',1)
   ```
5. You can use [`INSERT ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-select.html) here.

   ```sql
   INSERT INTO project
     (idorganisation, projectno)
   SELECT idorganisation, _prno
   FROM   user
   WHERE  usercol1 = SUBSTRING_INDEX(USER(),'@',1)
   ```

Therefore:

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`user1`@`%` PROCEDURE InsertProject(IN _prno VARCHAR(45))
  INSERT INTO project
    (idorganisation, projectno)
  SELECT idorganisation, _prno
  FROM   user
  WHERE  usercol1 = SUBSTRING_INDEX(USER(),'@',1)
;
```